# Solving $-1\le \frac{2}{x}$, I came up with 2 opposite solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Now let me reclassify my problem:

I was solving some inequality until I stopped at this step $-1\le\frac{2}{x}$ Why did I stop?

Because if I do this next step $-x\le 2$ and then multiply both sides by $-1$, I will come out with this $x\ge-2$

I try some inputs on the main inequality and figure out that I am wrong even though My algebra had no problems?

So I remember something and go back in time and do this $-1\le\frac{2}{x}$ swap denominator and numerator for both sides $-1\ge\frac{2}{x}$ then $-x\ge2$ then $x\le-2$

And by the power of the nature this one is correct even though I made a paradoxical step as I assumed that $-\frac{2}{x}>0$ so that I become able to reverse the inequality. At last $x$ is less than $-2$ which means that my assumption was right .

I now have a problem with the fact that Algebra fooled me up there giving me a wrong answer,or did it?

Put in mind that I put in mind that $x$ is never equal to zero, but that's not what I am here for.

Also to note I  do this stuff on the number line and that's what matters and then I can use the most suitable notation for my answer.

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: I want to add that you could also multiply both sides of the equation with $x^2$ which is always positive (except when $x=0$). Now it remains to solve the quadratic equation: $$-x^2 - 2x \leq 0$$ where you only should be careful with $x=0$. This is fairly easy since it factorizes quickly. The other options are also valid of course but this is a more direct method :)

Answer (score 2):

A principled way of solving this is as follows. Start with $-1 \leq 2/x$. There are now two cases: either $x$ is positive or $x$ is negative (as you say, it cannot be zero). Consider these cases individually.

- If $x$ is positive, then after multiplication of both sides by $x$ we get $-x \leq 2$ or $x \geq -2$. But since we assume $x$ is positive, this really means that the correct condition is $x > 0$.
- If $x$ is negative then when we multiply by $x$ we have to remember to flip the inequality, i.e., we then get $-x \geq 2$ or $x \leq -2$.

So the complete set of solutions is $x>0$ or $x \leq -2$.

Comment: So now you are saying that X is negative , how did you know that X is negative before solving it (sorry if it is a dumb question ) , In other words why did you take x<=-2 as your answer

Comment: @user597368 $x$ can be either positive or negative, so you have to consider both possibilities individually as their properties alter the answer

Comment: Ok so in this case for what reason is the solution x<=-2 and not x>=-2 ,again sorry if it is a dumb question

Comment: @user597368: that's it !

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply both sides of an inequality by a positive factor, the direction of the inequality remains. By a negative factor, it gets reversed. This rule is enough for you to solve the problem.

Starting from 
$$-1\le\frac2x$$

we multiply by $-x$. Then

- $x<0\implies x\le-2,$
- $x>0\implies x\ge-2$.

This is summarized by

$$x\le-2\lor x>0.$$

Comment: Can you please do the same but multiply by x instead

Comment: @user597368: do it if you like, the result will be identical (and you will probably multiply by $-1$ after multiplying by $x$).

Comment: When I do it I get X>=-2 When X>0

Comment: @user597368 So do I, so what's the problem ?

Comment: Look at your summarization it is not the same , I don't get that summarization then

Comment: @user597368: that's what you think. Perform the complete case analysis.

Comment: Well now I got it ,so you didn't take x=>-2 because it's not positive and took x>0 instead

Comment: Alright , Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Write $$-\frac12\leq\frac1x,$$
that is, the reciprocal of $x$ must be at least $-1/2$.  Surely all positive number are solutions and the negative ones must be at most $-2$.